# Derivation of Laplace-Young equation for excess pressure in air bubble

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

Isn't mentioned in my book and I'm having a hard time understanding where it came from. Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the physics stack exchange! Since this is not a typical help site, it would be great to ask questions to benefit the wider audience. You could improve your post by **elaborating your question, explaining where you encounter the problem and what your progress is so far**.

Comment: You can refer to this link for more details : [How to ask homework type questions on this site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)
 In case you find these rules to be a bit harsh,you can always (go to any other suitable sites)[https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh]

As someone said before, you can learn the alphabet from these sites and then come back here to ask questions about dinosaurs :)
Have a great time!

Answer (score 0):

[This document](https://www.ux.uis.no/%7Es-skj/PetFys04/Notater/Young-Laplace/you-lap.pdf) derives the Young-Laplace equation via two different methods: one using force balance and one by considering the minimisation of energy.